# Using eslint with a templating language

Tags: javascript, jinja2, eslint

We have a javascript file that can contain various combinations of functionalities based on user configuration.  I would like to use a templating language (probably jinja2) to manage the content.

However, we use eslint to check our formatting/style, and clearly jinja2 tags will break this.

I see two options:

- Ignore sections between `{{` ... `}}` and `{%` ... `%}` (not sure this is possible)
- Use a templating language that eslint has a configuration for (does this exist?)

I can't find information on either of these options.  Is there a way to do either of the above, or do i need to persue a different route all together?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jinja2

Comment: @Goran.it I did see this package, but at 3 weekly downloads I guess I was skeptical.  Fair point this does deserve a bit more investigation.

Comment: Actually this is weird. You have JS file and You want to use jinja2 in this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ESLint plugins](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins) can contain a `preprocess` method. This method takes the script's contents and filename as arguments, and returns an array of code blocks to lint. So one option would be to write a plugin which reads the script into a string using the `preprocess` method, and then performs string replacement on patterns that match with Jinja2 syntax.

For example, we know from the [Jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/) that the default delimiters are:

- Statements: `{% ... %}`
- Expressions: `{{ ... }}`
- Comments: `{# ... #}`
- Line Statements: `# ... ##`

And we can create regex patterns that match these delimiters:

- Statements: `\{%(.*?)%\}` [Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/ymHiNk/1)
- Expressions: `\{[{%]([\s\S]*?)[}%]\}` [Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/KNWTbc/1)
- Comments: `\{#([\s\S]*?)#\}` [Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/LPFBmr/1)
- Line Statements: `\#([\s\S]*?)##` [Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/3HCdcI/1)

So, in the `preprocess` method, we could use these patterns in conjunction with `replace` to replace the Jinja2 parts of the script with valid JavaScript. This would essentially cause ESLint to "skip over" the Jinja2 parts.

And that is, in a nutshell, what the [eslint-plugin-jinja](https://github.com/alexkuz/eslint-plugin-jinja) plugin does that @Goran.it suggested in his comment above. The only issue with this plugin is that the patterns may match on some non-Jinja2 things (i.e., false positives), or may not match on some Jinja2 things (i.e., false negatives). So you might have to tweak the patterns a bit for your use cases.

Below is a snippet example that uses the patterns from **eslint-plugin-jinja** to process a simple Jinja2 template. You can then run ESLint on this output and it should be error-free: [see the resultant code linted using the online ESLint linter](https://eslint.org/demo#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).

```js
let scriptString = `{# plain jinja variables are converted into strings #}

    var a = 'this is' + {{ some_variable }};

    {# if it is already in string, it is wrapped with spaces #}

    var b = 'this is {{ other_variable }}';
    var c = 'and this is {{ another_one['field']}}';

    {# if-else statements are converted into ( ..., ... ) expression #}

    var d = {% if something %} 'this is something' {% else %} null {% endif %};

    {# any other statements become comments #}
    
    {% for i in [1, 2, 3] %}
      console.log(a, b, c, d);
    {% endfor %}`;

function processScript(str) {
  const quote = '"';
  const processed = str
    // replace jinja comments with js comments
    .replace(/\{#([\s\S]*?)#\}/g, (str, val) => `/*${val}*/`)
    // treat if-else statement as ( ... , ... )
    .replace(/\{%(-?\s*if.*?)%\}/g, (str, val) => `(/*${val.substr(1)}*/`)
    .replace(/\{%(-?\s*(else|elif).*?)%\}/g, (str, val) => `,/*${val.substr(1)}*/`)
    .replace(/\{%(-?\s*endif\s*-?)%\}/g, (str, val) => `/*${val.substr(1)}*/)`)
    // replace jinja statements with js comments
    .replace(/\{%(.*?)%\}/g, (str, val) => `/*${val}*/`)
    // replace jinja expression tags in strings with spaces
    .replace(/\{[{%]([\s\S]*?)[}%]\}/g, str => str.replace(/['"]/g, ' '))
    .replace(/(['"])(.*?)\1/g, str => str.replace(/(\{\{|\}\})/g, '  '))
    // replace jinja expressions with strings
    .replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, (str, val) => `${quote} ${val} ${quote}`);
  return processed;
}

console.log(processScript(scriptString));
```

Comment: I'll have a more in detail look at this later, but this looks like a strong potential answer- thanks for the effort in writing it up!

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if I can help with anything else.